# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str), A high score saving function

Tags: python, file-handling

I'm currently trying to create a high score saving function that reads and writes from a file.

```
self.dir = path.dirname(__file__)
with open(path.join(self.dir),Highscore_File,"w") as f:
        f.write((self.score))
```

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I have tried converting `self.dir` to an integer but got an even more complex error.

Comment: Just a remark, if I am correct, `path.join` is supposed to join path, so not to be called with only one argument.

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message, as well as enough code/data to reproduce the issue. See: [ask], [mcve]. I'm voting to close this due to a lack of information, but it should also be closed because the issue was a single misplaced parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

```
open(path.join(self.dir), Highscore_File, "w")
```

should be

```
open(path.join(self.dir, Highscore_File), "w")
```

The error is because you are mistakenly passing 3 arguments to `open` and the third one is expected to be an integer

Comment: @Zenjeeh when an answer solves your issue remember to upvote and accept the answer. It is the way the effort is rewarded in SO.

Comment: @Cubo78 I tried to upvote but it told me because I have less than 15 interactions it counts it but is not show publicly, sorry mate.